# Counterexample separation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I am trying to understand, why the Separation Theorem from Hahn-Banach needs one of the sets to be open.

The theorem states:

$$\text{Re}\langle x',x_1 \rangle < \alpha \leq\text{Re}\langle x', x_{2} \rangle$$

for $x_1 \in C_1, x_2 \in C_2$ and  $C_1,C_2$ convex, disjoint sets with $C_1$ open.

Now I am looking at the example in $c_{00}$ referenced here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37551/a-counter-example-to-hahn-banach-separation-theorem-of-convex-sets

My trouble lies in understanding why $\mathcal{l}(x) = 0$ follows from $\pm \mathcal{l}(x) + \delta \mathcal{l}(y) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the inequality
$$
\pm l(x)\leq \delta\,l(y)
$$
holdsl for all $\delta>0$, you get that $\pm l(x)\leq0$. This forces $l(x)=0$.

The above is argued in the real case. In the complex case you would get $\operatorname{Re} l(x)=0$. As this can be done for the element $ix$, we also get $$0=\operatorname{Re}l(ix)=-\operatorname{Im} l(x).$$

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer! Further would I have $\inf_{\delta >0} l(x) \leq 0$ and $\inf_{\delta >0} l(x) \geq 0$ or how would you formalize another step before $l(x)=0$?

Comment: Yes, you can formalize it that way if you want. The way I think about it, $l(x)$ is less than all positive real numbers, so $l(x)\leq0$. Similarly, $-l(x)\leq0$, so $l(x)\geq0$. And this gives you $l(x)=0$.

Comment: I am having another question, if we have the sequence $a_n = (1/n,0,0,,...,0) n$ in $ \mathbb{N} $. Then the sequence should be in $C$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = (0,0,...,0)$ isn't. Isn't that a contradiction to $C$ being closed?

Comment: Assuming $C$ is the $K$ in fedja's answer, of course it is not closed. If it were closed you could apply Hahn-Banach between the closed convex set $C$ and the compact convex set $\{0\}$.

Comment: Okay... . in my textbook its described as an example of the first separation theorem, which assumes two open sets.

Comment: Well, none of the sets is open, so it is also a counterexample the negating some of the hypotheses of that theorem.